# Does restify support image upload at server side?

Tags: javascript, node.js, file-upload, image-uploading, restify

I am trying to create a REST API server that can accept image uploads with node.js restify. I looked at the documentation at http://restify.com/ but unable to ascertain if restify supports image upload as a server.

Does restify support image upload at server side? If no, which node.js module can one use to do image upload as server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[restify](http://restify.com) comes with a bundled BodyParser which is able to handle uploads (`multipart/form-data` only) and allow to have a custom handler (see `multipartFileHandler` option) for uploaded files read the [docs on BodyParser](http://restify.com/#bodyparser) for details and sample.

Comment: this will not be available on server side. this is form which is available in most client (browsers)

Answer (score 0):

Notice, there is a **req.files** attribute, which is a hash/object. Each value is also a hash, which a path property indicating the name and location of the uploaded file.